# RuntimeWarning: Enable tracemalloc to get the object allocation traceback

Tags: python

I read the Jupiter tutorial [Index](https://hub-binder.mybinder.ovh/user/ipython-ipython-in-depth-p6ebjnt6/notebooks/binder/Index.ipynb)

and tried

```
In [15]: print('before sleep'); sleep(12); print('after sleep')
before sleep
/home/me/anaconda3/bin/ipython:1: RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'sleep' was never awaited
  #!/home/me/anaconda3/bin/python
RuntimeWarning: Enable tracemalloc to get the object allocation traceback
after sleep
```

Very confused about the warning,

Answer (score 0):

This error means that the function (actually a coroutine) "sleep" was never executed.

Try to replace it with:

```
asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(sleep(25))
```

Otherwise, just use a non-asynchronous sleep method:

```
import time
time.sleep(25)
```

Good luck!